# Trying to open filePreview in console app (LWC/Aura)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, navigation, lightning-message-service

I'm trying to replicate this functionality, which opens a filePreview in a Standard App to work in a Console App:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__namedPage',
    attributes: {
        pageName: 'filePreview',
    },
    state : {
        selectedRecordId:[some_contentDocument_id]
    }
});
```

I know this functionality isn't supported in LWC, so I'm trying to let an aura component handle the actual opening of the preview via Lightning Message Service.

My code looks like this:

LWC:

filePreview.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-button label="Publish from LWC" onclick={publishMessageFromLWC}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

filePreview.js

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { publish, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import CONNECTOR_CHANNEL from '@salesforce/messageChannel/filePreview__c';

export default class PdfFileView extends LightningElement {
  @wire(MessageContext)
  messageContext;

  @api contentDocumentId = [some_contentDocument_id];

  publishMessageFromLWC(event) {
      const payload = { contentDocumentId: this.contentDocumentId };
      publish(this.messageContext, CONNECTOR_CHANNEL, payload);
  }
}
```

Aura:

filePreview.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService" />
    <lightning:messageChannel type="filePreview__c" onMessage="{!c.handleChanged}" scope="APPLICATION" />
</aura:component>
```

filePreviewController:

```
({
    handleChanged: function(component, message, helper) {
        var documentId = message.getParam('contentDocumentId');
        var pageReference = {
            type: 'standard__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                pageName: 'filePreview',
            },
            state: {
                selectedRecordId: documentId
            }
        };

        var navService = component.find('navService');
        navService.navigate(pageReference);
    }
})
```

Now this works in the sense that it opens a filePreview as expected, however, I'm still running into the same issue I was when using NavigationMixin in a LWC, namely: the entire page behind the preview gets disconnected.

I have checked whether the aura component is aware that it is in an app that uses console navigation with the workspace API and it is. I have also tried having the button be a lightning:button inside the same aura component and just handling the 'onclick'-event, to eliminate the LWC as the source of the issue (I also took the lwc off the page). That gives me the exact same result.

The whole reason I tried this was because to my understanding, aura does support Console Apps where LWC does not. Am I misunderstanding something? Should I use a different method to navigate? Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong here or how to fix it would be very welcome!